# why is there space between my li elements?

Tags: css

I have a list of items displayed horizontally. I want to create a border around each li, and have them jut up right next to each other.

I created a small test to illustrate the problem, [seen here](http://dabblet.com/gist/1916060):

```
<ul class="dashboard_inline_links">
    <li><a href="#">October - 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">November - 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">December - 765</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">January - 0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">February - 756</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">March - 2</a></li>
</ul>

.dashboard_inline_links li {
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1px;    
    display: inline;  
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
.dashboard_inline_links a {   
    border-color: transparent #C6D3F0;   
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1px;   
    color: #28478E;   
    display: inline-block;    
    margin: 0;    
    padding: 0;
}
```

In short - there is white-space between the list items. I want them to jut up next to each other, and now I can only accomplish this by setting margin-left = -3px on the li items.

Any idea what is happening? I feel like I am missing something obvious!

Comment: @jaredFarrish - thanks for the edit, I guess it makes sense to include such a small example directly in the question

Comment: It's caused due to browsers interpreting line breaks as spacing with inline objects. I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yes, but that tends to get messy in larger code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I could tell, you're setting the `li` to be `display: inline`, which means it will be treated like text in a paragraph. Hence, the `white-space` between the elements becomes a space that you visually see.

This should demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8F2XY/1/

Note, the following "resolves" the issue:

```
<ul class="dashboard_inline_links">
    <li><a href="#">October - 0</a></li><li><a href="#">November - 0</a></li><li><a href="#">December - 765</a></li><li><a href="#">January - 0</a></li><li><a href="#">February - 756</a></li><li><a href="#">March - 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8F2XY/2/

It's the absence of whitespace between the `li`s and betwen the `li`s and `a`s that fixes the code as-is.

Now, if you `float: left`, the element will become like a `display: block` element which will flow left in the display. Whitespace will be ignored.

So:

```
.dashboard_inline_links {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #C6D3F0;
    border-top: 1px dotted #C6D3F0;
    display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;
    padding: 6px 0;
    width: 916px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dashboard_inline_links li {
    list-style-type: none;
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1px;    
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
.dashboard_inline_links a {   
    border-color: transparent #C6D3F0;   
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1px;   
    color: #28478E;   
    display: block;    
    margin: 0;    
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8F2XY/

Comment: Yes, only float wasn't meant for this kind of job. `display: inline-block` is a more correct approach.

Comment: yes, the float does the trick. why won't inline work though? i dislike using float immensely

Comment: @Truth - Do you have a link to something that explains that statement?

Comment: @estherh - You can remove the whitespace between the `li`s, I suppose: http://jsfiddle.net/8F2XY/2/

Comment: thanks, I didn't think about the line breaks in there. makes perfect sense now

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Well, floats were originally meant for floating elements inside of inline text (such as images) and allow the text to naturally flow around it, without breaking the document. It wasn't meant for layout, that's what the newer `grid` rules and the `display` rules are for.

Comment: I can see that it's evolving with new properties and values to be more descriptive, but it's going to be a while before `float` stops being used for layout (as it took a while for `table`s to finally go away). Until new techniques firm up, I imagine `float` is going to be used in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `display:inline;` use `float:left;` in `.dashboard_inline_links li`

```
.dashboard_inline_links li {
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1px;    
    padding: 4px 8px;
    float:left;
}
```

See http://dabblet.com/gist/1916146

And this question: [What is the difference between Float:left vs Display:inline? While every element in browser goes to left by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702669/what-is-the-difference-between-floatleft-vs-displayinline-while-every-element)

Comment: Yes, only float wasn't meant for this kind of job. `display: inline-block` is a more correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of inline-block elements put a space (which usually is 4px wide) between next inline-block elements.

You can remove it using -4px letter spacing property.

http://jsfiddle.net/aAHXx/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that line breaks are interpreted as whitespace by browsers.

I haven't found a CSS workaround, but a very correct comment states that you should remove the whitespace altogether:

```
<ul class="dashboard_inline_links">
    <li><a href="#">October - 0</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">November - 0</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">December - 765</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">January - 0</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">February - 756</a></li><li>
    <a href="#">March - 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will work correctly in your current CSS settings. I'm still trying to find a CSS way though.

Comment: Note, even whitespace between the `li`s and the `a`s will be displayed as a space: http://jsfiddle.net/8F2XY/3/

Answer (score 1):

inline-block has a bad habit of putting spaces in between elements. it's natural by the way. this is caused by white-space between the `<li>`s

what you can do to remedy this are:

- put the `<li>` one after the other in single-file. meaning, leave no white-spaces, tabs or new lines:

just like this

```
//notice after the </li>, you follow another after it. no spaces!
<ul> 
    <li>item</li><li>item</li><li>item</li> 
<ul>
```

- or if you prefer having it in another line, comment-out the white-space. make sure that you start and end the comment after and before the `<li>`s respectively.

do this:

```
//notice after the </li>, you follow another after it. no spaces!
<ul> 
    <li>item</li><!--
 --><li>item</li><!--
 --><li>item</li> 
<ul>
```

i prefer the second. although messy, i can see the structure of the list.

Comment: thanks, that's a good alternative to one huge row of li's