# Vertically align left and right elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I wonder how to display:

- Header element `h1` aligned to the left of the `page-header`
- `button` element aligned to the right of the `page-header`
- Both elements being on the same baseline

Current code is pasted below and the working example is on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/janhsua5/1/). My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511135/h1-on-the-left-buttons-on-the-right-vertically-aligned) question, but proposed solution does not work for me.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
      <div class="page-header">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <h1>Hello World <small>Home Page</small></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `h1` has `margin-top` but the button hasn't. Add it the same margin..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your problem is with the CSS, not the markup

The fiddle you provided works as expected, the reason why the elements don't seem to align properly is because bootstrap sets a default margin on `h1` elements while it doesn't do so with `button`s.

The easiest way to fix this is to add

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

To your site's CSS.

Alternatively for similar output in a "bootstrappy" way, you can look into [bootstrap navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) and [branded bootstrap navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image).

Answer (score 1):

Remove top margin from header element:

```
.page-header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```