# How to align text boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to align following form all text boxes should at one line

```
<form action="AddItems" method="post">
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label"> Item Name</span>
                <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Item Id </span>
                <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="item_id" id="item_id"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Color  </span>
                <span class="ib"><input type="text" name="item_color" id="item_color"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Size</span>
                <span class="ib">  <input type="text" name="item_size" id="item_size"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Supplier </span>
                <span class="ib"><input type="text" name="item_supplier" id="item_supplier"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Quantity </span>
                <span class="ib">  <input type="text" name="item_quantity" id="item_quantity"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Unit Price </span>
                <span class="ib">  <input type="text" name="item_unit_price" id="item_unit_price"/></span>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <span class="label">Discount Percentage </span>
                <span class="ib">  <input type="text" name="discount_per" id="discount_per"/>
                </span></div>
            <div class="box">
                <input type="button" id="submit_items" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something similar to this.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FkzPv/1/)**

**The CSS Code:**

```
.box span.label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 80px;
}
```

*You can reduce/increase `margin-bottom` for less/more spacing respectively.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 div.box{
        display:inline;
        /* Or
        display:inline-block;
           Or
        float:left;
        */
    }
```

this will align all your text boxes inside div with class `box` as inline.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gksmg/)

for reference check this links :

- [Drawback of CSS: display:inline-block vs float:left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft)
- [Difference between Float:left vs Display:inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702669/what-is-the-difference-between-floatleft-vs-displayinline-while-every-element/1702795#1702795)

Answer (score 0):

> Do this. It's best way. This will work well on all browsers without compromising with design.

```
.box
{
float:left; /*or right according to your choice.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean vertical line, add this class :

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/dsMmf/)

```
.label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    min-width:150px;
}
```

---

but if you want to put `<input>`s in one horizontal line you must use floatfor `.box` like this:

```
.box
{
    float:left;
}
```

***note that*** you must set your container width as long as that all `.box` be in one line. line this: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/dsMmf/1/)